# Acceleration of the Expansion of Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Is the acceleration of the expansion of the universe (AEU) uniform in direction?  Meaning that if a particular direction in the sky is chosen and the AEU is measured and then other directions are chosen and the AEU are measured, do  all these measurements agree?

Comment: AFAIK, the measurements by Riess *et al* were originally taken in *all directions*.

Comment: I am fairly sure that all of our experimental evidence is consistent with an isotropic Universe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we know for sure. For example see [this article](http://www.cosmosmagazine.com/news/is-universe-expanding-asymmetrically/) (the paper is on the Arxiv [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0941)) suggesting that the acceleration could be anisotropic. However if there is an anisotropy then it's small, and to a first approximation yes the acceleration is isotropic.

Comment: Note that if this is true, then the cause of the acceleration is NOT dark energy, or at least not a simple dark energy like a cosmological constant.